# Karma unit test / STORE - state undefined

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, store, ngrx, ngrx-store

Everything works OK when running the application but in the Account unit test it seems like none or my states have been initiated. Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong? Here is the error.

Test error:
[image: Test error]

The create selector in index.js is returning a function with undefined parameters but only during karma tests.

Account.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import * as fromAuth from '../../../auth/store/reducers';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    <app-sign-up-form
      [user]="user"
      [account]="true"
      [pending]="pending$ | async"
      [errorMessage]="error$ | async">
    </app-sign-up-form>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  redirectSubs: Subscription;
  user: object;
  pending$ = this.store.select(fromAuth.getLoginPagePending);
  error$ = this.store.select(fromAuth.getLoginPageError);

  constructor(
    public store: Store<fromAuth.State>,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.redirectSubs = this.store
      .select(fromAuth.getUser)
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.redirectSubs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Account.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AccountComponent } from './account.component';
import { SignUpFormComponent } from '../../components/sign-up-form/sign-up-form.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { Store, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromAuth from '../../store/reducers';


describe('AccountComponent', () => {
  let component: AccountComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AccountComponent>;
  let store: Store<fromAuth.State>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AccountComponent, SignUpFormComponent ],
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({ fromAuth })
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AccountComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    store = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Store);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Auth.Reducer.ts

```
import * as auth from '../actions/auth.actions';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { AuthState as State, AuthStateRecord } from './auth.state';
export { State as AuthState };

export const initialState: State = new AuthStateRecord() as State;

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: auth.Actions): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case auth.LOGIN_SUCCESS: {
      return state.merge({
        loggedIn: true,
        user: action.payload.user,
      }) as State;
    }

    case auth.LOGOUT: {
      return initialState;
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export const getLoggedIn = (state: State) => state.loggedIn;
export const getUser = (state: State) => state.user;
```

Auth.state.ts

```
import { Map, Record } from 'immutable';
import { User } from '../../models/user';

export interface AuthState extends Map<string, any> {
  loggedIn: boolean;
  user: User | null;
}

export const AuthStateRecord = Record({
  loggedIn: false,
  user: null,
});
```

Authorization/index.ts

```
import { createSelector, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromRoot from '../../../core/store/reducers/root.reducer';
import * as fromAuth from './auth.reducer';
import * as fromLogin from './login.reducer';

export interface AuthState {
  status:  fromAuth.AuthState;
  loginPage: fromLogin.LoginState;
}

export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
  auth: AuthState;
}

export const reducers = {
  status: fromAuth.reducer,
  loginPage: fromLogin.reducer,
};


export const selectAuthState = createFeatureSelector<AuthState>('auth');
```

'State' here is undefined...

```
export const selectAuthStatusState = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  (state: AuthState) => state.status
);

export const getLoggedIn = createSelector(
  selectAuthStatusState,
  fromAuth.getLoggedIn
);

export const getUser = createSelector(
  selectAuthStatusState,
  fromAuth.getUser);

export const selectLoginPageState = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  (state: AuthState) => state.loginPage
);

export const getLoginPageError = createSelector(
  selectLoginPageState,
  fromLogin.getError
);

export const getLoginPagePending = createSelector(
  selectLoginPageState,
  fromLogin.getPending
);
```

Comment: From a first sight at the error, I would guess you might need to mock an `Observable` or two...

Comment: i have the same issue, have u got this fixed ?

Comment: Got the same issue any solution yet ?

Comment: did anyone managed to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `imports` array to `[ReactiveFormsModule, StoreModule.forRoot({}), StoreModule.forFeature('auth', {fromAuth})]` inside your spec file.

Answer (score 0):

```
const initialState: AppState = {
title: 'AshKeys',
name: 'Sojiro De Tenken'
};

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
imports: [TestModule],
declarations: [ExampleComponent],
providers: [provideMockStore({ initialState })]
})
.overrideTemplate(ExampleComponent, '')
.compileComponents();
```

Comment: you have to set your initial state as follows: