# ngrx testing: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxxx' of undefined thrown

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngrx

afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });I am currently trying to write tests for my ngrx based angular 7 application. The problem is that my test fails with the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxxx' of undefined thrown`. Here's how my test file looks like.

**explore-products.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";

import { ExploreProductsComponent } from "./explore-products.component";
import { provideMockStore, MockStore } from "@ngrx/store/testing";
import { IAppState } from "src/app/store/state/app.state";
import { Store, StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { appReducers } from "src/app/store/reducers/app.reducer";

describe("ExploreProductsComponent", () => {
  let component: ExploreProductsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExploreProductsComponent>;
  let store: MockStore<IAppState>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ExploreProductsComponent],
      providers: [provideMockStore()],
      imports: [StoreModule.forRoot(appReducers)]
    });

    store = TestBed.get(Store);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExploreProductsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("should create", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The only `should create` test is throwing the error. The error is being throwing by the `selector` somehow, which means the `xxxx` property is not initialized but I am not sure how to resolve it. Here's what my component looks like.

**explore-products.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { IProduct } from "src/app/models/product";
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";
import { selectProducts } from "../../store/selectors/product";
import { Store, select } from "@ngrx/store";
import { IAppState } from "src/app/store/state/app.state";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-explore-products",
  templateUrl: "./explore-products.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./explore-products.component.css"]
})
export class ExploreProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public productsLoading = true;
  public endpoint = environment.apiEndpoint;

  private productsSelector = this.store.pipe(select(selectProducts));

  public products: IProduct[];
  private subscriptionsArr: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions();
  }
  subscriptions() {
    const subcriberProduct = this.productsSelector.subscribe(products => {
      this.products = products;
      if (this.products !== null) {
        this.toggleLoadingSign(false);
      }
    });
    this.subscriptionsArr.push(subcriberProduct);
  }
  toggleLoadingSign(toggleOption: boolean) {
    this.productsLoading = toggleOption;
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    for (const subscriber of this.subscriptionsArr) {
      subscriber.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if I can provide any other information.

**Update**

The problem is with `AppState`. The error is thrown since the state is not initialized which causes the error to occur i.e `state.xxxx` is undefined. The error sometimes randomly doesn't occur. I am not sure how to fix this.

The same problem is also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503034/karma-unit-test-store-state-undefined). But no solution

Answer (score 14):

For me adding this line of code `afterEach(() => { fixture.destroy(); });` in all my spec files injecting `provideMockStore()` fixed this issue intermittently triggering.

```
describe('Component', () => {
  let component: Component;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const state = { featureKey: { property: value } }; // The state of your feature snippet
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({ initialState: state }),
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => { fixture.destroy(); });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

For me adding:

```
  afterEach(() => {
     fixture.destroy();
  });
```

to every spec file of a component solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.
See how I've created mock store and used it. Added single line comments (with ************) wherever code was updated:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";

import { ExploreProductsComponent } from "./explore-products.component";
import { provideMockStore, MockStore } from "@ngrx/store/testing";
import { IAppState } from "src/app/store/state/app.state";
import { Store, StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { appReducers } from "src/app/store/reducers/app.reducer";

describe("ExploreProductsComponent", () => {
  let component: ExploreProductsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExploreProductsComponent>;
  //Update the store def.************
  let store: MockStore<any>;

  beforeEach( async(() => { //*****************UPDATE
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ExploreProductsComponent],
      providers: [provideMockStore()],
      //Change to imports************
      imports: [StoreModule.forRoot({})]
    }).compileComponents();//*****************UPDATE
    //Removed this
    //store = TestBed.get(Store);************

  }));//*****************UPDATE

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExploreProductsComponent);
    //Get store instance************
    store = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Store);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("should create", () => {
    //Spy on store actions************
    const spy = spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
   //Test is store is called properly************
   expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(Your params)
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I get the following error `Type 'Store<{}>' is missing the following properties from type 'MockStore<any>': state$, initialState, scannedActions$, setStatets` on the line `store = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Store);`

Comment: @Mj1992 - Updated the anwer check the updates (//*****************UPDATE). Try if that works.

Comment: getting the same error on the same line. It is unable to compile the tests due to this error.